# PyQt app doesn't exit when i close the window

Tags: pyqt5

`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(534, 423)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 161, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 534, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionCopy = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionCopy.setObjectName("actionCopy")
        self.actionPaste = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPaste.setObjectName("actionPaste")
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionCopy)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionPaste)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.actionCopy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Copy"))
        self.actionCopy.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Copy a file"))
        self.actionCopy.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+C"))
        self.actionPaste.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste"))
        self.actionPaste.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste a file"))
        self.actionPaste.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+V"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionNew.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Create a new file"))
        self.actionNew.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+N"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Save a file"))
        self.actionSave.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+S"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

I export this code from pyqt designer  but when i clicked close button kernel did not stop, code was running. I could not run other code kernel was stuck on this code in spyder

Whenever i execute the code and close the window, it closes,but the python console in the IDE doesn't return the exit code,

Comment: Just call `app.exec()`, remove `sys.exit`.

Comment: it didn't work @musicamante

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408620/cant-kill-pyqt-window-after-closing-it-which-requires-me-to-restart-the-kernal

Comment: solution : add "app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)"in main